# preg_last_error() saying no error when there appears to be an error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

**EDIT**: I understand this is a hard to replicate issue, but if someone could suggest pointers as to what would be probable cause for this issue, that would be really helpful.

**EDIT**: As requested, here's `$content`:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tHecParp

It's an extracted web page. `create|exited|deleted|updated` are samples, i'm looking for keyword المحتجين in this.

**The following code runs continuously inside a while loop:**

```
$pattern = "/(create|exited|deleted|updated)/";
$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $matches );

var_dump( $num_found );

if( $num_found === false )
{
    if (preg_last_error() == PREG_NO_ERROR) {
        var_dump( 'There is no error.' );
    }
    else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
        var_dump( 'There is an internal error!' );
    }
    else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR) {
        var_dump( 'Backtrack limit was exhausted!' );
    }
    else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR) {
        var_dump( 'Recursion limit was exhausted!' );
    }
    else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
        var_dump( 'Bad UTF8 error!' );
    }
    else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
        var_dump( 'Bad UTF8 offset error!' );
    }
}
```

I am simply looking for a few keywords inside a *text file read into `$content`.*

**Output**

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(1)
int(1)
int(1)
bool(false)
string(18) "There is no error."
bool(false)
string(18) "There is no error."
bool(false)
string(18) "There is no error."
```

It finds one keyword a couple of times, then starts returning false. **While testing this, I have kept `$content` constant**. So it must continue finding the keywords, instead it returns false. But `preg_last_error()` does not help.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting a false?

Comment: Can we see the content, so we can test ourselves?

Comment: could you show the entire loop so we can see the condition

Comment: The pastebin link to the contents of $content doesn't seem to work. Also, could we get the while loop and the declaration of any variables used included in the code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PCRE Limit had exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989985/large-regex-patterns-pcrc-wont-do-it)

There is a limit to the size of the pattern you can use.

> The  maximum  length of a compiled
> pattern is 65539 (sic) bytes if PCRE
> is compiled with the default internal
> linkage size of 2. If you want to
> process  regular  expressions  that
> are truly enormous, you can compile
> PCRE with an internal linkage size of
> 3 or 4 (see the  README  file  in the
> source  distribution and the pcrebuild
> documentation for details). In these
> cases the limit is substantially
> larger.  However,  the  speed of
> execution is slower.

http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 0):

Your source example is incomplete and makes it tough to track down this issue. The most likely cause, even though your example as I used it works just fine, is that your pattern has an problem. Is your pattern changing at some point in the loop? preg_match_all() will return **FALSE** and preg_last_error() will return **PREG_NO_ERROR** if the pattern you specify **fails to compile**.

There are other edge cases, but this seems the most likely. Can you update the link to $content and provide the full source for the while loop?