# Large regex patterns: PCRC won't do it

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a long list of words that I want to search for in a large string. There are about 500 words and the string is usually around 500K in size.

PCRE throws an error saying `preg_match_all: Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 704416`

Is there an alternative to this? I know I can recompile PCRE with a higher internal linkage size, but I want to avoid messing around with server packages.

Comment: Do you really need regex to do that?

Comment: How else can I do this? The string is basically an extracted webpage. I'm looking for matches of words within webpages. Any alternative suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: What kind of output do you want?

Comment: If they are just strings, use `strpos()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `strpos()` is far less expensive than a regex.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that and report back

Comment: Adding to Bart's, strpos is indeed faster: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#95875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you approach the problem from the other direction?

1. Use regex to clean up your 500K of HTML and pull out all the words into a big-ass array. Something like \b(\w+)\b.. (sorry haven't tested that).
2. Build a hash table of the 500 words you want to check.  Assuming case doesn't matter, you would lowercase (or uppercase) all the words.  The hash table could store integers (or some more complex object) to keep track of matches.
3. Loop through each word from (1), lowercase it, and then match it against your hashtable.
4. Increment the item in your hash table when it matches.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you might consider tokenizing your input string instead, and then simply iterating through each token and seeing if it's one of the words you're looking for?

Comment: It's the process of breaking a string down into smaller pieces, called 'tokens' - essentially, break your string into an array of words, then check each word to see if it's in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/).

One of it's strengths is that uses automata theory to guarantee that the regex runs in linear time in comparison to it's input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_word_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) or [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string on whitespace (or whatever dilimeter makes sense for the context of your document) then filter the results against you keywords.

```
$allWordsArray = str_word_count($content, 1);
$matchedWords = array_filter($allWordsArray, function($word) use ($keywordsArray) {
   return in_array($word, $keywordsArray);
});
```

This assume php5+ to use the closure, but this can be substituted for [create_function](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) in earlier versions of php.